# Display Count in cell with Excel & VLOOKUP w/Contains for certain letters

Tags: excel, function, count, ms-office, vlookup

Phew, that was a lot to write as a title.

I'm looking to display a count within a cell, the count would source from a search of another sheet & column utilizing (I assume) VLOOKUP.

Example:

So, I want to look for all values in Sheet2/Column A that contain "SMITH"

Then, in Sheet1/A1, a count of all those values of "SMITH" would show up (let's just say 122)

So, I have 122 Smiths' in sheet2/ColumnA and the number, 122 (count) shows up in Sheet1/A1

I hope that makes sense. I'm pretty green (obviously) to Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&"Smith"&"*")
```

With column A being where the names are.

Comment: You also need the `Sheet2!`, as the OP requested the formula is on Sheet1 but the data is on Sheet2.

Comment: Scott, I bow down to you!

One other question, what if I wanted to double click on that number, and it take me to the filtered results? Is that possible? Kind of like when you do a count of a pivot table set.